# How to add multiple bases in /etc/default/jetty

Tags: jetty

I am trying to add multiple jetty bases to jetty server. Documentation says it is possible without providing the information on how to do it.

So in /etc/default/jetty file with single jetty base is which works is

`JETTY_HOME=/opt/jetty`
`JETTY_BASE=/opt/jetty/my_base`
`JETTY_USER=jetty`
`JETTY_HOST=jetty`
`JETTY_ARGS=jetty.http.port=8989`
`JETTY_LOGS=/opt/jetty/logs/`

i have tried combinations

`JETTY_HOME=/opt/jetty`
`JETTY_BASE=/opt/jetty/my_base`
`JETTY_BASE=/var/www/domain1`
`JETTY_BASE=/var/www/domain2`
...

i have also tried ',' comma separated does not work

`JETTY_HOME=/opt/jetty`
`JETTY_BASE=/opt/jetty/my_base, /var/www/domain1, /var/www/domain2`
....

Has anyone managed to get this working, can you let know how to achieve this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create more `/etc/default/<name>` entries.

Say you want 3 bases.

Lets call them `tau`, `upsilon`, and `phi`.

You'll create ...

```
/etc/default/tau
/etc/default/upsilon
/etc/default/phi
```

each of which is a standalone instance of Jetty, with their own `${jetty.base}` directory and a common `${jetty.home}` directory.

The `jetty.sh` you (likely) copied into place for your service entry also needs the same name.

So, `cp jetty.sh /path/to/service.d/tau.sh` becomes how `/etc/default/tau` is used/searched for.
(Note: depending on your chosen shell, a symlink will probably work too)